# Content gets out of parent and goes to the next element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an element with an image and some text next to it, The content is centered inside the parent.

When I try to add more elements after the image and the text, As you see the green text with red border overflows the parent `.about` and goes to the next parent `.contact-us`

Here is a fiddle to view and edit the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/04rmefx7/

Here is the code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Start about */

.about {
  background-color: #dad04a;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%
}

.about img {
  height: 100px;
}

p{
  border: 4px solid red;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* End about */


/* Start contact-us */

.contact-us {
  background-color: #eeb03c;
}


/* End contact-us -->
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Start about -->
<div class="about text-center">
  <div class="inline-block">
    <img class="pull-left" src="https://placehold.it/600">
    <div class="pull-left text-left">
      <h4 class="inline-block">Heading</h4>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <br>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <br>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
      <br>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
      <br>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et velit officia alias harum nam illum pariatur deleniti reprehenderit, aliquam, commodi iure modi, facilis error dolorum doloribus. Porro, hic explicabo dolores. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore dolor explicabo quas, est, iure non repellendus eaque, nemo eum repudiandae voluptatem rem quos iste a. Non nisi aliquid consequuntur. Libero!</p>
</div>
<!-- End about -->

<!-- Start contact-us -->
<div class="contact-us text-center">
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
</div>
<!-- End contact-us -->
```

Comment: Could you please provide more detail about the desired result ? are you trying to place the image in the middle ?

Comment: Did you remember to clear the floats? Also remove the 100% height and use `min-height` instead.

Comment: @MahyarMottaghiZadeh, The `<p>` element at the end of the about section goes to the next parent, I want it to be inside the about section

Comment: @Paulie_D, There is a `div` with class `clearfix` after the image and the text

Comment: Please check the lorem text in green with red border, To get what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you to remove `height: 100%` from `.about`?